# How to upload an OSG-model to Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, openscenegraph

I am programming with [OpenSceneGraph](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/) (OSG) and I want to put my created OSG-model into Google Earth.

I did research, but I could only find that Sketchup can directly upload its model to Google Earth, but couldn't find anything about uploading an OSG-mode.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Fixed grammar, added openscenegraph tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting your model to COLLADA (DAE) which Google Earth can import.

OSG needs to be built with the COLLADA-DOM library in order to have the COLLADA .DAE loader/saver, and the COLLADA-DOM library is non-trivial to get working.